# how to connect a lineEdit with a function that defines a variable?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals, python-3.7

i hope i can explain my problem correctly. I have a pyQt5 GUI with lineEdits, for Example lEUMDicke. When the text changes, i want to define a variable, for example UMDicke, with a function that changes the , to . and read the variable as a float. My python version is 3.7.

```
class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        self.lEUMDicke.textChanged.connect(lambda self.UMDicke: (self.vardecl(self.lEUMDicke)))

    def vardecl(self,varstring):
        try:
            r = varstring.replace(",",".")
            rvalue = float(r)
        except:
            None
        return rvalue
```

I'm very thankful for every answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making lEUMDicke a class variable, you do not need to pass it as an argument as it can be accessed with the self keyword. Furthermore, using bare except is bad practise, and especially with just None inside it. If an error occurs that you dont expect, you generally want the program to crash so you know what happened. In terms of expected errors, I think (may be wrong) python throws a ValueError if it cant convert to float, therefore just try to catch the ValueError.

There is also a 'Validator' class is Qt that can help prevent the user from entering letters etc.

'''

```
class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    self.lEUMDicke = QLineEdit()
    self.lEUMDicke.setValidator(QDoubleValidator())
    self.lEUMDicke.textChanged.connect(self.vardecl)

@pyqtSlot()
def vardecl(self):
    try:
        r = self.lEUMDicke.text().replace(",",".")
        rvalue = float(r)
    except ValueError:
        print("Cannot convert to float")
        return -1
    return rvalue
```

'''

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried the code but i have some further questions:

I have lots of variables, so i wanted to define one function for every variable. Is that possible?
lEUMDicke is the LineEdit and UMDicke the variable, is your Code right?

Comment: I dont exactly understand the question. If the other variables will also be converted to float from QLineEdit, just connect them to the vardecl function, (but in that case you will need to pass arguments). Otherwise you have to make new functions.